# Nested resources links in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources

I have controllers that work "in context" of some model. Example: controllers UsersController and InvoicesController can work in context of Company model - they show users and invoices for some company. I use nested resources as routing solution and have URLs like

http://localhost:3000/companies/8/users

What is the easiest and flexible way to make links on index view, that will reflect on context?

It means that
new_user_path or
new_company_user_path
will be created depending on context. I don't want to use a lot of if...then's. 
Is there any solution?

Comment: You mean in your `user` `index` view, you want to have a dynamic method that generates a nested resource link like `new_company_user_path` if the parent class is `Company` and a `new_account_user_path` if the parent class is `Account`?

Comment: Sorry, I mean new_company_user_path

Comment: If no context specified (company in this case) then will be used new_user_path; with "Company" context will be used new_company_user_path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get away without ANY if switches, but you can write a helper to at least keep it out of your view code.

I would suggest you look at the `url_for` helper in Rails and use that inside a helper like this:

```
def conditional_path(action)
  if (params[:company_id]
    url_for(:controller => 'users', :action => action, :company_id => params[:company_id])
  else
    url_for(:controller => 'users', :action => action, :invoice_id => params[:invoide_id])
  end
end
```

Something like this, you can get as fancy as you want with your helper

Comment: Works for me:  
= url_for :controller => 'invoices', :action => 'show', :id => 123, :company_id => params[:company_id]  
= url_for :controller => 'users', :action => 'show', :id => 123, :company_id => params[:company_id]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can keep it nice and simple with array routes:

```
= link_to 'Whatever', [:new, @company, @account, @user]
```

If @company is present you'll get new_company_user_path, if @account present new_account_user_path or if neither new_account_path etc. I'm not at my dev comp so can't test this out.